# How to convert imageSet to idx3-ubyte format, using mnisten,

Tags: converters, convolution

I am trying to use a CNN code to train 10 images stored in an imageSet. The CNN code rather uses the idx3-ubyte format.

I want to know how to convert from my imageSet data to idx3-ubyte format.

I came across the mnisten command  below, but I don't have any Idea how to use it.

Please help.

```
  %Here is my imageSet code that I want to convert to idx3-ubyte format.

  %% Load image dataset

 imgFolder1 = fullfile('C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\practical-cnn-2015a\NairaNotes');

 trainingSet = imageSet(imgFolder1, 'recursive');

 %% 
 for digit = 1:numel(trainingSet)

numImages =    trainingSet(digit).Count;           

        for i =  1:numImages

            img = read(trainingSet(digit), i);
            im = rgb2gray(im2single(read(trainingSet(digit), i)));
        end



 end

 %% here is the mnisten command I got, but I don't have an idea how to use it 

 mnisten -d my_image_files_directory_name -o my_prefix -s 32x32
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I assume you're on Windows, check out [this guide](http://zzcoder.cn/2016/07/21/windows%E4%B8%8B%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91mnisten/).